# LMM multifactor swaption calibration

Tags: libor, libor-market-model

Brigo and Mercurio give Rebonato's approximation for Black-like swaption volatility as

$(v^{LFM}_{\alpha,\beta})^2=\sum^\beta_{i,j=\alpha+1}\frac{w_i(0)w_j(0)F_i(0)F_j(0)p_{i,j}}{S_{\alpha,\beta}(0)^2}\int^{T_a}_0\sigma_i(t)\sigma_j(t)dt$

How would I interpret this result in a "factor reduced" aka "multi-factor" or "n-factor" context?

Assuming I have a functional form for $\sigma_i(t)$, do I define my $n$ factors in terms of various $\{T_i\}$ such that $\alpha \leq i \leq \beta$, and also such that there are $n$ separate $\sigma_i(t)$, each with their own calibration parameters?

This does not seem like the correct approach to me, since if I had, for example, one factor, then any two swaptions with expiry at time $i$ would have the same approximated volatility.